# Using a timer to fade an image in and out

Tags: java, timer, fade

So im making this sort of intro to a game and I want to have a couple of little image logos fade in and then out but so far everything I've tried has either kept an infinite loop in the background which will crash at some point, it doesn't execute properly, or it fades in and doesn't fade out. Help is much appreciated. 
Also ive been using the getAlpha() setAlpha() methods.

```
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() 
    {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            {

                if(opening1.getAlpha() <1)
                {
                System.out.println(opening1.getAlpha());
                opening1.setAlpha((float) (opening1.getAlpha() + 0.00005));
                }
                else
                {
                    timer.purge();
                }
            }
        }

    },1*1,100);
    }
```

Comment: Use a `javax.swing.Timer` to adjust an opacity value and trigger a repaint. In the repaint, make sure you respect that opacity value.

Comment: Show us what have you tried so far. Read carefully the http://stackoverflow.com/tour and try to post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I tried using a timer but I kept getting loops I couldn't figure out how to end it

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using java.lang.Math class. I would recommend using the "exp(double a)" method.
Paired with System.currentTimeMillis() or System.nanoTime() you can call it inside a loop and it "Returns Euler's number e raised to the power of a double value."

The exponential function naturally grows slowly, so I would use a multiple of some constant to manipulate how fast the function increases. Obviously you would just take the value you get from this function and use it in your setAlpha() method.

I use the Math class all the time when programming my games. Another helpful one is the sin() and cos() methods.

To refine this approach I would set an initial time before the loop, say 0, then add the current system time every iteration through your loop.